# React-Datepicker: How can I change the navigation arrows?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I have a situation, where I am supposed to change the navigation arrows available by default in **react-datepicker** component.

**What did I found and tried?**

I found the datepicker uses a `button` tags and uses the class to apply the icons as below:

```
<button type="button" class="react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--previous react-datepicker__navigation--previous--disabled"></button>
<button type="button" class="react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--next"></button>
```

I tried implementing the background with an expected image on right/next navigation button as:

```
.react-datepicker__navigation--next {
    background: url(../images/rightArrow.png) no-repeat !important;
    right: 10px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me up in how to change the image on navigation images?

**NOTE:** I checked the react-datepicker documentations and other SO queries, but nowhere found any relevant help on this so far.

Comment: it would be more efficient if you'd provide a real working example instead of pasting a screenshot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're talking about [this datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-28) component - they build arrows using borders. So to use custom images for arrows it'd be enough to set appropriate `width` and `height` for particular arrow button and eliminate border.

Using your example it seems that next would work:

```
.react-datepicker__navigation--next {
    background: url(../images/rightArrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Plus One to the BullsEye Solution... Thank you So Much